# Using pure Ember to create SVG chart with transition effect

Tags: ember.js, d3.js

I'm trying approach in this link [D3 and React - the future of charting components?](http://10consulting.com/2014/02/19/d3-plus-reactjs-for-charting/) to create some charting components without using `d3` to generate svg elements.

Now I could do the most simplest case: if I have an array `[1, 1, 1]`, I will get a series of bars with height equal to 1. When I change the array to `[2, 2, 2]`, I get a series of new bars with height equal to 2 instantly.

What I want to have is, when I change data array, the bar could change height with an animation effect. For the above input, the second time height of each bar would grow from 1 to 2.

Inside my component I use `each` to iterate through values

```
{{#my-svg}}
  {{#each values as |v|}}
    {{my-rect height=v ........}}   // my own component
  {{/each}}
{{/my-svg}
```

It looks like Ember will destroy and recreate all `rect` components instead of doing virtual dom like diff to change their `height` property (I'm using Ember with glimmer engine). Therefore my css transition property no longer works. (It works if I only have one `<rect>`)

Another way in my mind is adding `oldHeight` `newHeight` for each bar, use other jquery library to change `height` with transition based on those two values. But if that so I need to run this function for every bar, which sounds very slow. I'm wondering is there any better to achieve it.